# Debian lspci doesn't show sound card

Tags: ubuntu, audio, debian, kernel-module, soundcard

I have a problem with different Debian distributives, problem relative to the sound card. I am not able to find it in the system

```
# lspci | grep Audio
```

doesn't show any audio device. I already read about kernel and modules and familiar with modrpobe, lsmode, etc. The question is

**if a device does not show via lspci are there any chance that it would be founded on the system after the right driver (with right parameters) will be loaded?
 Or if the system doesn't see needed PCI device there wouldn't be any sense in trying to load device module.**

Thank you for your help, it would be very helpful. Btw I am using the following chipset Pegatron IPXPV-D3/DC

**UPDATE**

Seems that my problem was relative to hardware, the issue was solved with the new motherboard. 
Mark this thread as closed. Thanks

Comment: That board supports HDA, right? Do you have `lspci` output of it? Please, share.

Comment: It might be working with ALSA SoC in I2S mode which might be a platform driver! Output of `aplay -L` ?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possible alternatives here:

First, run `lspci` without `grep` and look at the results one by one - maybe there's an audio card there that goes by a different name, or even goes by "audio" with lowercase (your grep search is case sensitive, thus it would ignore "audio" and it would only show you "Audio" matches).

The second alternative is to run `lsusb` and see what you get there - in some cases computer internal parts may be connected via internal USB.

I hope that helps!